# How to add Item to cart on ListView Django/

Tags: python, django

I am making django app, adding items to cart in detail-view work fine but i struggle with implementation the same on ListView. What should I do? I get an error on ListView Post  - N`o Item matches the given query.`

views.py

```
 class ShopListView(ListView):
        model = Item
        template_name =  'shop/home.html'
        context_object_name = 'items'
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
            item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=pk)
            orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order_item=item)
            order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_user=request.user)
            order.save()
            order.order_items.add(orderItem)
            return HttpResponse('Items added')
```

Also if i do post(self,request,pk) as in DetailView i get an error one argument is missing 'pk'.

```
class ShopDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item 
    template_name = 'shop/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(item=self.object)
        context['form'] = CommentCreationForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if 'buy' in request.POST:
            item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=pk)
            orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order_item=item)
            order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_user=request.user)
            order.save()
            order.order_items.add(orderItem)
            return HttpResponse('Items added to the database')
        if 'comment' in request.POST:
            form = CommentCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False)
                comment.comment_user = request.user
                comment.item = Item.objects.get(id=pk)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponse('post-created')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('post not created')
```

DetailView works fine.

Comment: I get the error **The view myApp.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Answer (score 0):

Your DetailView subclass works because it receives object pk from url kwargs. But in the case of the ListView subclass, you need to pass the pk as a Post parameter in the request and then retrieves it:

```
class ShopListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'shop/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=pk)
        orderItem, _ = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order_item=item)
        order, _ = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_user=request.user)
        order.order_items.add(orderItem)
        return HttpResponse('Items added')
```